# CloudFouncdy CLI and multitenancy, many environments/deployments

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a simple way to save configs (`~/.cf/config.json`) with alias or something and use CF CLI with different tenants without re-login?

I'm looking for something like the BOSH's aliases for environments: https://bosh.io/docs/cli-v2/

---

**EDIT**

Please vote for this [feature request](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1503) if it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [cf-targets-plugin](https://github.com/guidowb/cf-targets-plugin). It lets you have many targets that you can switch between.

Comment: `cf save-target` causes `Error: symlink ... A required privilege is not held by the client.` on Windows.
I think that is better to do it [in this way](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1503)